# How to deselect the row, when lost focus for a table in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, focuslistener

In order to select a row, I use this code:

```
table_2.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
          @Override
          public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event1) {
          if (event1.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
                  Point point = event1.getPoint();
                  int column = table_2.columnAtPoint(point);
                  int row = table_2.rowAtPoint(point);
                  table_2.setColumnSelectionInterval(column, column);
                  table_2.setRowSelectionInterval(row, row);
          }
       }
  });
```

Then, to reset the highlighted line, I use this code:

```
table_2.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
       table_2.clearSelection();
    }
});
```

But I would like to know, is there **any other way** to reset the highlighted line?
So I got:

```
table_2.getSelectedRow()==-1
```

Comment: Why do you want to search another way? It looks perfectly fine to me..

Comment: Why do you need another way? What's wrong with `clearSelection()`?

Comment: @RealSkeptic: When I click on the right button, and then lose focus, the selection is not reset.

Comment: Are you editing the cell? Or just selecting it?

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: i am just selecting it of right button. The edit is disabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In order to select a row, I use this code:

Easier way is to use:

```
table.changeSelection(row, column, false, false);
```

> Then, to reset the highlighted line, I use this code:

When you click on another cell in the table there is no focusLost(..) event generated because focus is still on the table. There is no need to clear the selection because the selection is automatically cleared when you click on another row, using the code I suggested.

```
if (event1.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
```

Don't use "MouseEvent.BUTTON3", people don't know what that means. Instead use

```
//if (SwingUtilties.isRightMouseButton( event1 ))
if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton( event1 ))
```

which is easier to read and understand.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But where should I use `table.changeSelection(row, column, false, false);`?

Comment: @Tomas, Instead of setting the column and row selection intervals.

Comment: Please tell us why Eclipse proposes to create a constant , when I use `SwingUtilties.isRightMouseButton( event1 ))`.It is this constant:  `protected static final SwingUtilities SwingUtilties = null;`

Comment: @Tomas, I made a typo, in the code I posted. I spelt "Utilities" wrong. I forgot the second "I".